# Get an email content ready to be sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, office-js

I am developing an app using officejs. I wanted to take some content from the excel worksheet and put it in an outlook email. Then I don't want it to be sent by the system but rather open to me the new email so I would be able to control it and if I would be satisfied I will send it manually.

I tried with Nodemailer but can't find the way to do it. It just offered me the function of transporter.sendMail which automatically send the email from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature of opening a mail compose form from Excel is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response . I posted the idea